# Math.pow() floating point number as exponent

Tags: javascript, floating-point, pow

I want to pass a floating-point number as the second argument (exponent) to `Math.pow()`. I always get `NaN` when the passed number is not a *whole number*, like 0, 2, 7, you name it. Is there a working way in javascript to make this work?

```
(function () {
    var notice = document.getElementById('notice');
    var value = 0.0;
    var interval = 0.02;
    var timeInterval = 10;
    function interpolation(x) {
        var y = Math.pow(Math.e, x);      // <<< HERE >>>
        console.log(x, y);
        return y;
    }
    function animation() {
        var callAgain = true;
        if (value >= 1) {
            value = 1.0;
            callAgain = false;
        }
        notice.style['opacity'] = interpolation(value);
        notice.style['marginTop'] = (value * 20 + 20) + 'px';
        value += interval;
        if (callAgain) {
            setTimeout(animation, timeInterval);
        }
    }
    animation();
})();
```

*PS: Please don't comment, that an opacity greater than 1 doesn't make any sense. I know that `e^x; x > 0` will yield values greater than `1`. I'll insert a proper function when I got this working.*

Comment: `Math.pow(2, 4.5);` (for example) works for me in chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constant is `Math.E`, not `Math.e`

Comment: And `Math.exp(x)` would be a better way to compute this.